# Error in Restful web service

Tags: java, rest, jersey, restful-url, jersey-client

I am new to Restful web service, when I try to run my code am not getting 404 error. 
My project structure
[image]

index.jsp

```
<a href="webapi/firstApp"> link</a>
```

Web.xml

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.sasi.wb.MyFirstAppilcation</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

MyFirstAppilcation:

```
package com.sasi.wb;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
@Path("/firstApp")
public class MyFirstAppilcation {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getMsg(){
        return "Got It";
    }
}
```

Url:
http://localhost:8004/webserivcetraning/webapi/firstApp

I don't know what I missed here. When try to click my link in index.jsp I get 404 error. Can anyone help me to resolve?

Comment: if you are looking for working example please check this(http://javaant.com/restful/#.VliJ-GQrJuU)

Comment: you are trying to access the class itself, you should access the method inside the class, i mean provide the path for method and then access the method. check this example http://javaant.com/restful-web-services-using-jersey/#.VliL1WQrJuU. Download the code from git. and try

Comment: Thanks Nirmal. I corrected my mistake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this

```
<param-value>com.sasi.wb.MyFirstAppilcation</param-value>
```

`jersey.config.server.provider.packages` Tells Jersey what package to scan for your `@Path` classes and register those classes. Unknown listed packages are ignored. What you listed is not a package, it is a class, so your class is never registered. So Just remove the `.MyFirstAppilcation`

Comment: Thanks Peeskillet. I corrected my mistakes it works fine now.